# Disable web browser's default autocomplete on kendo multiselect

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm creating a kendo multiselect from a select input.  The kendo control renders out a basic input text box and a custom drop down that is displayed as you type.  The issue I'm having is that the input it triggering the default web browser autocomplete dropdown which is overlaying the kendo dropdown.  I need to disable the default web browser behavior so that only the kendo dropdown is displayed.  I've tried adding the autocomplete="off" attribute to the select tag that the kendo multiselect is initialized from but the resulting  tag that is rendered by kendo does not carry this attribute over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I simply used the 'input' field off of the kendo object to access the input and then added the attribute after the kendo control was initialized

$('#multiSelect').data('kendoMultiSelect').input.attr('autocomplete', 'off');

This resolved the issue

Comment: Despite having answered your own question, this is a helpful little gem that saved me a big headache. Clicking on the kendo multi-select would unavoidably open a second autocomplete box as meant for a text field, but this fixes it. Thanks mate.

Comment: This partially solved it but it didn't work for address related fields. I had one called "state" and had to also add role="presentation" to the tag. $('#multiSelect').data('kendoMultiSelect').input.attr('autocomplete', 'off').attr('role', 'presentation');